# Reshape melted data to wide table in pandas with True/False as values where variable has value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, reshape

Given data as follows:

| x | y |
| --- | --- |
| a | d1 |
| a | d2 |
| b | d1 |
| b | d3 |

would like to create:

| thing | d1 | d2 | d3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | True | True | False |
| b | True | False | True |

example data:

```py
data_from_csv = 'x,y\na,d1\na,d2\nb,d1\nb,d3\n'
data_to_csv = 'thing,d1,d2,d3\na,True,True,False\nb,True,False,True\n'


----------

I thought there was some sort of unstacking which could be done here but I can't seem to get it working.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) with test not equal `0`:

```
df = pd.crosstab(df['x'], df['y']).ne(0)
print (df)
y    d1     d2     d3
x                    
a  True   True  False
b  True  False   True


df=pd.crosstab(df['x'],df['y']).ne(0).rename_axis(index='thing',columns=None).reset_index()
print (df)
  thing    d1     d2     d3
0     a  True   True  False
1     b  True  False   True
```